# FFMPEG says "No such file or directory" when trying to convert image sequence

Tags: ffmpeg

From the shell, when I specify a sequence of images via `%d` in the input filename, FFMPEG insists "No such file or directory", despite evidence to the contrary. Looking online, I haven't managed to find any references to generating video from a sequence of images using FFMPEG where `%d` is not used, yet it seems to fail here.

My images should be identified by FFMPEG from `img%06d.gif`. Issuing `ls img[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gif` succeeds in the very same directory I issue the FFMPEG command.

The command I use is:

```
ffmpeg  -i img%06d.gif -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv720p test.mp4
```

What could possibly be going wrong???

Comment: Did you check that the image names are starting from 1 or in your case `img000001.gif` ?

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output. `yuv720p` is not valid for `-pix_fmt`, and declaring `-r` as an output option will cause ffmpeg to convert from `-r 25` (input default) to `-r 30` (output) resulting in duplicated frames.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following definitely works:

```
ffmpeg -i images%06d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 test.mp4 -y
```

However **it doesn't work with GIF pictures**.

You can losslessly convert your pictures to PNG and run the above command line.